# /etc/issue file does not get reflect without login logout

Tags: systemd, login, virtual-machine, logout, getty

I changed my /etc/issue file to display IP and system info with background color, and built a system which run on CentOS 7, but problem is when i deploy my machine on ESX it display regular /etc/issue file containt and after login and logout to Virtual console it display correct things with my changes !

This is just after deploy i see

[image]

and after i login and logout i see correct things !

[image]

can someone please suggest me how do i get it fixed ?

Thanks

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want `getty` to go back into the past and change the issue that it has *already finished sending to the terminal* after you edit `/etc/issue`? Sounds like time travel...

Comment: no i want getty restart after boot finish _because i tried ssh and getty@tty1 restart and i can see Virtual console shows my desired window_ **in blue screen**

Comment: Then I guess you can just restart `getty` as you say. This sounds a lot like a non-problem.

Comment: Yes i am checking this in packing and get back here !

Answer (score 0):

The scripts which get ip and system info will be run on boot, so i restart getty@tty1 in same script and it worked.